# Second Select disabled if Option 1 in first Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have two select boxes. I need the entire second select box to be disabled until the user selects any option other than the first option in the first select box.

This is my logic but I can't quite execute it.

```
if 
     .first-select = option-1 
then 
     .second-select .attr('disabled').
else
     .second-select .removeAttr('disabled')
```

Comment: someone there added an answer ```
  $('.first-select').on('change', function() {
    $('.second-select').prop('disabled', this.selectedIndex === 0);
  }).change(); // trigger the event once on DOM ready```
Which is working but then they deleted their answer!

Comment: I noticed the question wasn't tagged with jQuery, so I deleted the answer temporarily for updating it with a vanilla JavaScript example.

Comment: thanks, updated tags to include jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `selectedIndex` property:

```
var 
    firstSelect = document.querySelector('.first-select'),
    secondSelect = document.querySelector('.second-select')
;

function changeHandler() {
   secondSelect.disabled = firstSelect.selectedIndex === 0;
}

firstSelect.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
changeHandler(); // execute the handler once on DOM ready
```

Or if you are using jQuery:

```
$('.first-select').on('change', function() {
   $('.second-select').prop('disabled', this.selectedIndex === 0);
}).change(); // trigger the event once on DOM ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
$("#first_select").on("change",function(){
if(this.selectedIndex != 0){
$("#second_select").removeAttr("disabled"); 
// or you can do this $("#second_select").prop("disabled",false);
});
```